# LibGDX static AssetManager

Tags: java, static, libgdx, asset-management

I am having some trouble figuring out the proper use of libGDX's AssetManager class. From what I understand, you are never supposed to create a static instance of an AssetManager. The alternative that people suggested was to pass around the AssetManager reference to every single class that uses it. I'm wondering if what I have proposed below is another safe alternative.

```
public class GdxGame extends Game {

    private AssetManager assets;

    ....dispose, create AssetManager etc


    public static AssetManager getAssets() {
        return ((GdxGame) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).assets;
    }
}
```

I really don't want to have to pass an AssetManager or an Assets class around to every single class in the game, so I'm trying to figure out a solution that allows some kind of static referencing. Is this safe?

Comment: How many classes do need access to your assets and why? It sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I would think many. Every entity (human, zombie, explosion) will need to reference the class no?

Comment: You should only need direct access to your assets in a few classes. Your entities should only have to be provided a skin or atlas or regions or whatever you prefer, but certainly should not be responsible for accessing your AssetManager. You might want to reconsider your approach. Don't make game objects responsible for accessing assets, they should not need to care about that.

Comment: Perhaps they would not have direct access to the actual AssetManager class, but would they not need access to some sort of central asset bank to access their textures/animations?

Comment: No, there is no reason why a game object should be aware of its visual representation. If it's convenient for you to store that info along with the entity then you can certainly do that, but that doesn't make the entity responsible for that. You might want to read into object oriented design and separation of concerns if you want to read more about that.

Comment: Okay, so say it is convenient for me to store that info with the entity. If the entity isn't responsible for getting its assets, then I guess I have to pass each asset through the entity's constructor or some other setter methods? That's not feasible since I would have to do it for every single instance of that type of entity. As for a game object not being aware of its visual representation, are you saying that I should have a game object class, solely containing data, and a completely separate class that pulls this data and draws the object with it's own asset information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113079/discussion-between-grimrader22-and-xoppa).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be feasible to separate responsibilities? Although that's not related to your original question. So you might want to join #libgdx on freenode instead, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-Help.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Anyway, regardless of who has access to what, is the way I reference the AssetManager safe?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "safe". You probably wont ever notice a problem with it though, except maybe for some very unlikely edge cases.

Comment: Edge cases being an invalid context because of the android life cycle? Or I've avoided that?

Comment: there's no such thing as an invalid context (at least not related to this), but you could have multiple contexts. Overall, as said, it sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I could have multiple contexts, one therefore being invalid, no?

Comment: No, indeed. You are deviating from the original question and using the comments as chat. I'll leave you with this. I think I gave you enough options and answers to work with. If you like to ask a new question then please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you worry too much :-) The static instance you suggested originally will be perfectly adequate and functional for your purposes:

```
private static AssetManager assets;
....dispose, create AssetManager etc

public static AssetManager getAssets() {
    return assets;
}
```

The only trap for young players to avoid is when you pause an Android app: on resume, just reload the AssetManager and its assets before continuing. Don't worry about semantics - if it works for you, then it's fine. Happy days :-).

Comment: So in main 'Game' class' onResume method I should just reload the assets? Is this the right place to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that one will get called even on the desktop version where it's unnecessary. Override onResume in your AndroidLauncher instead.